# Allow users to access my beta subdomain but pass link juice to the main site

Tags: seo, redirects, robots.txt, backlinks

My site can be accessed by either `http://example.com` or `http://beta.example.com`. The sub domain beta is the same site but a different version and I want users to be able to use the beta but any links gained on the beta domain I want the link juice to pass to the main domain.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Never treat Googlebot any different than actual site visitors*

You should never treat Google bot any different from actual users. Redirecting Googlebot using user agent or other similar tactics and not users will likely harm your site as its against Google's guideline rules.

*Cosmetic changes say hello to canonical links*

If the beta site has the same content but different cosmetic changes through CSS then you should use [canonical links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) pointing to the master pages that way any links gained on beta will pass to the main domain.

*If the content is different*

If the content is actually different then you should not attempt to redirect Juice as this again will not go well with Google, if you want the juice to flow to the main site then you should run it on the main domain with a sub folder `/beta/`.

Comment: I should add that if the sub-domain is not to be indexed, then you should have a robots.txt file that restricts indexing.

Comment: @closetnoc If you block the subdomain with a robots.txt file then the pages won't be crawled, the `rel="canonical"` tag won't be seen and no "link juice" will be passed to the main domain. If the subdomain's pages have a `noindex` robots meta tag (or HTTP response header), then again I doubt they will pass "link juice". The canonical link (for same content pages) _should_ prevent the beta pages from appearing in the SERPs, however, in order to (try to) pass "link juice" I think there will always be a chance that the beta pages could be indexed?

Comment: @w3d Yes. You are right. It is a catch 22 but I think I would still block using robots.txt. It does not mean that the page with a link will not be crawled. It will be despite the robots.txt as a result of following the link but not indexed fully (unless something has changed recently). It would not be crawled under normal circumstances. Remember recently Google was spidering pages as a result of a link and placing the page in the index without a snippet due to robots.txt file? That is what I am referring to. I could be way off base though. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is with a rel canonical link tag in the `head` of each of your pages.

So the home page of both your main site and your bet site would have this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/" />
```

And `foo.html` on each would have this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/foo.html" />
```

That way Google knows which is your preferred site.  Google will also treat all inbound links to the beta site as if they pointed to the main site.

Comment: A caveat should be added, only use canonical tags if the content is the same, or very similar on both pages.